# laravel sanctum consulta relacionada

Tags: sql, laravel

como podría realizar la siguiente consulta sql en laravel sanctum?

consulta SQL

```
       SELECT  informes.rut_usuario as rut
      from informes  
       inner join users 
       on informes.rut_usuario = users.rut
       WHERE users.rut = "19999999"
```

//laravel controlador: en esta funcion necesito crear la consulta de arriba, la idea es que el usuario logueado pueda listar sus informes.

// esto fue lo que intente

```
  public function listInforme(){
  $rut_usuario = auth()->user()->rut;
  $informes = Informe::select('users.rut')
 ->join('informes', 'users.rut', '=', 'informes.rut_usuario')
  ->where("users.rut", $rut_usuario)
 ->get();
  return response([
    "status" => 1,
    "msg" => "¡Listado de informes!",
    "data" => $informes
  ]);

}
```

// y el error por consola es el siguiente

```
  "message": "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 
   Not unique table/alias: 'informes' (SQL: select `users`.`rut` from 
  `informes` inner join `informes` on `users`.`rut` = 
  `informes`.`rut_usuario` where `users`.`rut` = 19999999)",
```

Comment: Buen día, te recomiendo hacer el [tour] y leer la sección [ask]. Es desmotivante entrar en una publicación con la intención de ayudar y ver que el usuario no ha mostrado que ha investigado o intentado algo. Puedes [edit] tu pregunta y agregar el código que tienes hasta el momento y los errores que recibes, o en su defecto mostrar lo que has investigado. El objetivo de este sitio es ayudar a las personas que muestran un esfuerzo por resolver sus propias preguntas. Si la solicitud es del tipo alguien hágalo por mi, tal vez un sitio de `freelance` sea mejor opción.

Comment: ahi lo edite, no esta seguro como hacer la consulta

Answer (score 0):

Hay dos formas de solucionar este problema el primero es relacionando el modelo usuario con el modelo informes por medio de eloquent

en el modelo usuario:

```
public function informes(){
   return $this->hasMany(Informes::class, 'rut_usuario', 'rut');
}
```

y en el controller te quedaria algo asi:

```
$informes = User::with('informes')->find(Auth::id())->informes;
```

y la otra manera es con un inner join como lo haces arriba te quedaria algo asi:

```
$informes = Informes::join('users', 'informes.rut_usuario', 'users.rut')->where('users.id', '=', Auth::id())->get();
```

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Lo voy a revisar, gracias por responder

Comment: No me  han funcionado, hay alguna forma de no pasar el id?